# Need to get my RPi 3 to work with two UART devices

Tags: uart, gps

I am working on a project and I am trying to connect a GPS receiver to the RPi through uart and a TNC-Pi (Terminal Node Controller) Both of the instructions want me to use "*ttyAMA0*" and move bluetooth to "*ttyS0*". It is imperative that I do not change the TNC at all, so I will need to change the port for the GPS. How do I do this?

[TNC-Pi instructions go to pg 14](https://tnc-x.com/TNCPi.pdf)

[Adafruit Ultimate GPS for RPi UART](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-ultimate-gps-on-the-raspberry-pi/using-uart-instead-of-usb)

Edit:

After doing a little research I can use a SPI-to-UART chip, but still have no idea as of yet how that is going to work

Answer (score 2):

The Pi3 has only two accessible GPIO (14/15) which may be used as a UART and provide one serial link.

You can use other GPIO as a software UART if you know how to write software and are pretty competent doing so.

The alternative is to use serial to USB dongles.

Comment: The serial usb dongles will not work for what I am trying to do. It has to fit in the large Smarti Pi hat cover and be portable. Where can I find infomation on making software UART's?

Comment: You should add that restriction to your question.  My [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/) has support for software serial links.  I reiterate it requires a familiarity with writing software.